About a proof of the existence of a certain function. ("Topology Second Edition" by James R. Munkres)
In "Topology Second Editon" by James R. Munkres, the author proved the following proposition.

The explanation that a function is a box that takes an input and produces an output has strongly influenced me.
We can get the value of $h(i)$ for any $i\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ since $i$ is finite.
So, if we consider a function is a box, then there exists the function $h$.
But at the same time I know a function from $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ to $C$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{+}\times C$ which satisfies certain properties.
If we consider a function is a box that takes an input and produces an output, the above proposition is obvious and we don't need the proof, but if we consider a function is a subset of a cartesian product which satisfies certain properties, we need to prove the above propostion.
Is this correct?
